# problema con envió y recibir datos con ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

tengo el siguiente código en un js pertenece a un ajax, el problema es el siguiente, que en mi form tengo puros inputs de tipo select, entonces mande al data los datos por redundancia algo tipo json entonces si captura los datos como tal, pero no se si realmente los envia por post, ya que no me retorna nada.

```
jQuery("#form_filtroscajas").submit(function( e ) {

   var _servicio = $("#servicio").val();
   var _producto = $("#producto").val();
   var _estado = $("#estado").val();
   jQuery.ajax({
            url: "ubicacion de mi php",
            data: {servicio: _servicio, producto: _producto, estado: _estado}, 
            type: 'POST',
            success:function(data){             
                if(data == "success"){
                    location.reload();
                }else{
                    // alert(data);
                    alert("error");
                }
                return false;
            },
            error: function( XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
                return;
            }
          });
          e.preventDefault();
            });
```

en mi php que recibe estos datos los tengo así para despues manipularlo para lo que requiero. pero cuando el ajax devuelve los valores manda vacio, intente poner un datatype de tipo json pero igual marca error soy muy novato tocando este tema sobre json o ajax.

```
$servicio=$_POST['servicio'];
$producto=$_POST['producto'];
$estado=$_POST['estado'];
```

Comment: Saludos. Verifica que la respuesta del PHP que se llama en el AJAX realmente recibe y manipula los datos que recibe; asi como se obtienen los datos que se devolveran y todo su proceso hasta que finalmente son incluidos en la respuesta.

Comment: Creo que es un efecto mas bien de tu propio codigo tanto del frontend como del backend, en el frontend (javascript) estas enviando cierta informacion, pero en el backend estoy casi que seguro que no estas devolviendo nada, en conclusion: siempre te saltara un error del lado del frontend pero mostrado como alert (porque eso pusiste en tu codigo), quiza el problema es simplemente que no estas devolviendo ninguna respuesta desde `PHP` a ajax.

Comment: lo se Riven pero el problema que creo que no manda los datos al php, mande a imprimir un array que contenga los datos de esos valores para que me muestre a pantalla y me los manda como null